# synchronising objects between two buckets in same account with the directory structure

Tags: amazon-s3

I have two buckets B1 and B2 I have many objects in B2 with inside separate folders and I wanted to sync with B1 with the folders

I tried
aws s3 sync s3://B2 s3://B1
but only the objects are synced without folder structure

Answer (score 0):

You can use `s3cmd sync -r` for recursive syncing your folders.